# Does window.open not work inside an AIR html component?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air

I have a component in AIR like so:

```
<mx:HTML
        id="html"
        width="100%" 
        height="100%" 
        location="https://example.com" 
        locationChange="dispatchLocationChange(event)"
    />
```

The page it loads contains this:

```
<a onclick="alert('onclick')">Alert</a>
<a href="javascript:alert('js')">Alert</a>
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank')">new window</a>
```

The 2 alerts both work. however nothing happens when you click the new window link.

all 3 links works when in a real browser so I know its ok.

Is there just no support for window.open in the AIR HTML component? or is this a bug?

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out you need to extend the class `HTMLHost` and override the `createWindow` method like this:

```
override public function createWindow(windowCreateOptions:HTMLWindowCreateOptions):HTMLLoader
{
    var window:Window = new Window();
    window.open();
    window.visible = true;


    window.height = windowCreateOptions.height;
    window.width = windowCreateOptions.width;


    var htmlLoader:FlexHTMLLoader = new FlexHTMLLoader();
    htmlLoader.width = window.width;
    htmlLoader.height = window.height;
    htmlLoader.htmlHost = new MyHTMLHost();

    window.stage.addChild(htmlLoader);

    return htmlLoader;
}
```

Then set this subclass as the htmlHost property for the `HTML` component.

This does get it to work. But there is some strange behavior in the new popup window. Seems kinda buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Try: [`navigateInSystemBrowser`](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=showdetails&postId=9243).

[Example](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=showdetails&postId=9243):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical">
<mx:Script>
      <![CDATA[
            private function init():void
            {
                  html.htmlLoader.navigateInSystemBrowser = true;
            }
      ]]>
</mx:Script>
      <mx:HTML location="test.html" id="html" creationComplete="init()"/>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```